# Ruby on Rails Helper in Controller Refinery CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I am utilizing Refinerycms for my web application.  I created an engine and I created a helper called PostsHelper.  I want to be able to utilize the helper in my view (obviously), but it does not work.  I have been looking over some example code for a Refinery blog, and it uses something like the following in a controller:

```
 helper :posts
```

However, when I add this code to my Posts controller I get the following error:

```
 LoadError in PostsController#index

 Missing helper file helpers/posts_helper.rb
```

This is my posts helper:

```
 require 'nokogiri'

  module PostsHelper
def readMore(post)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(post.message)
    intro = doc.search("div[class='intro']")
    result = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(intro)
    result << link_to("Read More", post_path(post))
    result.to_html
end
```

So ultimately I am confused on how to "have a helper help a view" in an engine.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: In what path is your `posts_helper.rb` file?

Comment: Hey, it's vendors/engines/posts/app/helpers

Comment: Have you tried placing it in your own `app/helpers`?

Comment: Not yet, but I figured there was a way to keep all the engine code together.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was provided in IRC Refinerycms channel.

I added the following in the path: vendor/engines/posts/lib/refinerycms-posts.rb

```
 config.to_prepare do
    ::ApplicationController.helper(PostsHelper)
  end
```

Comment: I had to add this to an extension: the above code has to go in the Engine class, i.e. vendor/extensions/<type>/lib/refinery/<type>/engine.rb
but this works perfectly